# Superclasses header not available in Protege 4.3

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am using protege 4.3 and pizza tutorial from 130.88.198.11/tutorials/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf (href not working as the link has numeric domain) but there are lots of discrepancies like superclasses header is not present as shown in following picture:-

[image]

further a couple of widgets that tutorial talk about could not be found in protege. Please guide me which plugins exactly required for Superclasses header (which is hindering me from adding restrictions) and generally for all other functions. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you point to a particular page or figure number that has something that your version of Protege doesn't?  The things you see in, e.g., Figure 4.30 should be present when you select a class from the hierarchy in the Classes Tab.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have placed the screen shot. The Superclasses header should have been there as the tutorial (Page 40, Exercise 16) says. Please help.

Comment: @Landon Ashes Isn't the "Superclasses" the "SubClassOf" header you have in your snapshot? I think that in the newer version they just have changed the label. The same applies to the "Equivalent Class" header. In your version is "Equivalent To". So in the tutorial, whenever they refer to the "Superclasses header", just do it in the "Subclass Of" header. It is the same. For example, DeepPanBase is subclass of PizzaBase. The superclass of DeepPanBase is PizzaBase...

Comment: @DanielGarijo You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @DanielGarijo From the point of view of correct answer. yes you are right. But my problem is that the documentation that says "A Practical Guide To Building OWL Ontologies Using Protege 4..." do not go along quiet well with my Protege 4.3. There are so many such difference. So is there any resource using protege 4.3 or do you suggest i should install earlier version of Protege? eg. Superclass and subclassof are quiet different in implementation. We have to use different procedure for them respectively!

Comment: @LandonAshes the implementations for both are the same. Protege reads the "rdfs:subClassOf" relationship. The tool implementers just changed the label of the header in the newer version, but if you create an ontology in an older version, the OWL will be the same as in the new one. I don't think you need an older version of Protege for the tutorial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "Superclasses" header is the "SubClassOf" header you have in your snapshot. In the newer Protege releases they must have changed the label of the header.

The same applies to the "Equivalent Class" header mentioned in the pdf of the tutorial. In your version is "Equivalent To". Therefore, in the tutorial, whenever they refer to the "Superclasses header", just assume it is the "Subclass Of" header.

For example, DeepPanBase is "subClassOf" PizzaBase. That is the same as saying that the "superclass" of DeepPanBase is PizzaBase.